# Losing current selection of list item after updating the listview items using notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-widget

I need to refresh the ListView items every second, and it works fine using notifyDataSetChanged(). After the refresh, the already selected item in the list is losing its selection. ie, it loses its selected item background. How can I maintain the selected state of already selected item, after each refresh?

Thanking u for the support in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood your question your query is that you are losing the selected item focus of the ListView after refreshing the ListView. So, for that you can use `ListView's setSelection() method` to set the selected item in the ListView. So, when you refresh the ListView after that you can set the item that you want to be selected or the previous selected using `setSelection().`

```
listView.setSelection(position)
```

Here `position` is the position that was the last selected index before `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Thanks Lalit. I have tried ur solution. It is getting selected on key up and down actions only, but not on touch/click of the item. How can we achieve the same? Also, on selection, the marquee effect of text is also not coming. Please help in this regard.

Comment: hmm I guess you have a custom ListView, right?. If yes then you have to add android:focusable="false" to other views to make ListView clickable.

Comment: Yes I am having a custom ListView. What did u mean by other views?- Other views in the layout which contain the ListView, or the views in the custom layout for a list item? Also, dont we need to implement setOnItemClickListener() for the ListView?

Comment: Other Views = View of ListView Row that you have.

Comment: not working :(  but, what about setOnItemClickListener() implementation?

Comment: setOnItemClickListener() will be in your Activity Class not in the Adapter class.

Comment: But after updating the list, the selected item might have a different position?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it seems the issue of `Recycling` .If you want to refresh your view on a time interval you can use `notifyDataSetChanged().` But you have to maintain your state of the listview.

For example you select a second position and now when you scroll listview or refresh the adapter then the state of the selected position will gone.So you have to maintain a array for selected item's position so that in `getView()` method of the Listview you can check that weather the array contains the position or not.If array contains the position that means this item is selected so you can change the controls value according to it if array does not contains the value that means that item is not selected.

Also if you are using checkbox or radio or other for display selection of the List-view then you have to implement the events like for checkbox either `checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener()` or `checkbox.setonClickListener()` same as radio and in this event you have to maintain the array of the selected items.

First you have to check weather the array contains the selected position or not? If not contains then add that position in the array and if yes then just remove that position from the array and refresh the adapter.

Comment: I don't think that the User has the issue of checkbox here. User is asking about the selected item being refreshed after the ListView is refereshed.

Comment: Thanks for ur input Dharmendra. But, as Lalit commented, i need to get back and show the selected item in the ListView as highlighted, after the refresh.